# Material UI console warnings in react strict mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, strict-mode

As fast as the application is growing the console is dirty as a footballer shirt.

---

#### What do I mean?

Material UI in strict mode throws warnings like FindDomNode, or to use `strings` instead of `booleans` in props.
The problem is that the console is like a red wall in development mode, but I don't want to get rid of `strict mode` I want to get rid of these warnings.

I have an idea to create a 'warnings whitelist' to hide the well-known warnings, but actually, I don't know how to do it in a proper way.

The goal is to see new, more dangerous warnings/errors in the console clearly.

Perhaps there is a better way to solve my problem, but my research did nothing. If you have any idea I'll be really glad to hear it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [material-ui Drawer - findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61220424/material-ui-drawer-finddomnode-is-deprecated-in-strictmode)

Comment: You will not receive that error in production mode. If you want to not receive that error in dev  go in `index.js` and remove `StrictMode`

Comment: @Florin  Read the whole post before you leave a comment. And you even didn't read the title of the post, cuz react has not strict mode inside index :)

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Nope. This unfortunately doesn't answer my question. I don't want to get rid of strict mode or use unstable components.

Comment: This is a Mui existing problem. StrictMode with console flood, or don't use strict mode. period.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I do know it. Read the whole post and you will get to know what I want to reach.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically related to the browser console:
And not a long term solution, but if you ever need to cut down on noise.

You can use a negation filter in the browser:

-MUI

You can also filter out multiple things by delaminating with spaces.
-MUI -someOtherWarning

[image]